# Zipping up a directory and uploading it to local maven

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm attempting to zip up a directory of minified javascript and css, and then publish it to my local maven repo.

I can't simply publish the artifact, because publishing requires the `install` task, which is only available if I include BOTH the `maven` AND `java` plugin.

Including the `java` plugin produces a jar file, which I do not want.

I've attempted to use the `maven-publish` plugin, but it also seems to only want to publish .jar and .war files.

Is there any way to simply zip up my build directory (which only contains minified js and css produced from gulp) and upload it to my local maven repo without involving unneeded plugins?

Comment: Are you talking about Maven or Gradle? THe relationship to task sounds more like gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can simply declare your own [`Upload`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.html) task to accomplish this.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

task install(type: Upload) {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file://${System.getProperty('user.home')}/.m2/repository"
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives archiveTask // replace with name of task that builds you .zip
}
```